# Python - Can you use list comprehension to replace the value at a particular list index?

Tags: python, list, replace, list-comprehension, element

I currently have a bunch of lists defined something like below:

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'm currently replacing the first element of that list then placing the contents of the list into a dictionary (where the key is the old element 0 value) by doing the following:

```
old_value = old_list[0]    
old_list[0] = 'new value'
test_dict[old_value] = old_list
```

I was wondering, is this the best way to accomplish this? I was wondering if there was a way to make this a bit more efficient with list comprehension so it could look something a bit more like this:

```
test_dict[old_list[0]] = [i for idx, i in enumerate(old_list) if '''relevant conditions to replace element 0''']
```

Comment: If I point you to [*dict comprehensions*](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension), will you be able to find a solution? (You'll need a way to loop over the bunch of `old_list`s, though)

Comment: I'd say that your original approach is fine, though it's definitely possible with a list comp. `test_dict[old_list[0]] = ['newvalue' if idx == 0 else i for idx, i in enumerate(old_list)]`

Comment: Try: 
`[i if idx != 0 else "new_value" for idx, i in enumerate(old_list)]`

Comment: The list comprehension builds a new list, though, rather than simply making an in-place replacement of one element in the original.

Comment: Thank you! Both @Austin and pythonic833 's answers accomplished what I was going for, but it's good to know that my original approach was a good solution too :)

Comment: @user3153443 keep in mind that the list comprehension is not the most memory (and time efficient) solution. Simply replacing one element is way more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

**Code**

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_value = 'new'
test_dict = {}
test_dict[old_list[0]] = [new_value] + old_list[1:]
print(test_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{1: ['new', 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

**Generalised form**

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
idx = 2
new_value = 'new'
test_dict = {}

test_dict[old_list[idx]] = old_list[:idx] + [new_value] + old_list[idx+1:]
print(test_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{3: [1, 2, 'new', 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A readable form can be achieved with unpacking:

```
head, *tail = old_list

# if test_dict already exists
test_dict[head] = ["new value"] + tail

# otherwise
test_dict = {head: ["new value"] + tail}
# {1: ['new value', 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: This is not the same if `test_dict` already exists.

Comment: It doesn't really matter much though, I personally think it's fine for the purpose of inspiration, nobody should be copying it letter for letter without understanding what it does.